# PHP RAR Русские символы Cyrillic.

Tags: php, rar

Есть стандартный метод взятый с официального сайта php который извлекает файлы с архива:

```
/* example by Erik Jenssen aka erix */

$filename = "foobar.rar";
$filepath = "/home/foo/bar/";

$rar_file = rar_open($filepath.$filename);
$list = rar_list($rar_file);
foreach($list as $file) {
    $entry = rar_entry_get($rar_file, $file->getName());
    $entry->extract("."); // extract to the current dir
}
rar_close($rar_file);
```

Проблема заключается в том что если в архиве "foobar.rar" есть файл с русским названием, к примеру qweабв.txt то он распакуется со следующим именем: qwe То есть прерывается на русских символах. Я понимаю что можно потом изменить название средствами php. Но хотелось бы узнать возможно ли сделать это ещё на выходе чтобы сохранение происходило корректно.

Comment: Как вариант - переименовать файл

Comment: Ещё вариант использовать консольный rar и средствами пхп вызывать его с нужными параметрами. Это медленее если нужно достать несколько файлов а не весь архив. Даже может быть намного медленее. Но проблем с русскими файлами быть не должно в этом случае.